# GitLab behind HAProxy, includes invalid url in e-mails to users

Tags: gitlab

I have a couple of services that need to be available on different urls on port 80, but run different web servers. HAProxy is listening to port 80, and sends all traffic for http://.lan to http://.lan:8123.

I have gitlab setup and running on port 8123, therefore the url in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb is

```
external_url 'http://*****.lan:8123'
```

All works well. I can access the site on port 80. The issue is because the external_url is setup with a port, any e-mails sent to users include links back to the site on port 8123.

How can I continue to run the site on 8123, but not send this on e-mails to users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: did you make it work

Comment: Yeah I'll post up the solution once I'm in the office tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

Just change `external_url` to the URL you want to see in your emails.

Be aware however, if you use a different protocol in your `external_url` (ie. forward proxy from HTTPS to HTTP), you need to [take care of some extra headers](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticitycant-get-past-login-pageredirected-to-login-page).